# How to add a mysql function inside the values array while running an sql query in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, arrays

I want to insert data into a table and I am running the query in node.js app.
So I've created an array of values so that data could be inserted in a single query.
One column in my table is log date and it accepts data which is given by

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP()*1000
```

function.

I dont want to change table schema but instead want to send this in query. Also I dont want to use for loop to run separate query to enter each row.

I added this function in values array but node.js doesn't know it and if I add this function as string then the query gives error.

```
let values = [
[5000, 1],
[6000, 2],
[8000, 3]
];

let query = `insert into price_table (price, id,log_date) values ?;`;
await db.query(query, [values]);
```

how do I put value for log_date as UNIX_TIMESTAMP()*1000

Comment: Each value in the `values` array represents `[<timestamp-multiplier>, <id>]`?

Comment: 1st value is price, 2nd value is Id, I want to add 3rd value also which must be UNIX_TIMESTAMP()*1000